# Do I need to remember the hard-code for different sorts?

Tags: sorting

I am currently a freshmen in college doing some self-studying about the different sorting algorithms.

My studying source does provide the codes and I did some practice on it (coding the sorting base on the concept it). At the moment, I can provide selection sort with just a little bit of trouble (coding that is).

Am I required to memorize the codes? I know the difference between the sorts and the concept behind it. Do I need to memorize the Pseudocodes behind it as well? Will interviewers ever ask you to produce the codes on the spot?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to memorize the exact code syntax , but it would be important to understand the logic behind the sorting algorithms (ie. be able to explain using pseduocode).

I've been asked in interview how to do some basic sorting algorithms like a bubble sort, but nothing very complex. I was not required to write the exact "code" in any particular language, but just prove that i know the logic and can explain how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome on Stack Overflow. I'm answering your post below, even though it will be closed as `too broad` or `primarly opinion-based`, because this QA site is oriented towards coding questions. You might want to ask this on another QA site, like programmers stackexchange.

> Do I need to memorize the Pseudocodes behind it as well?

not really, as in every decent language you'll have a standard library that offers you state of the art implementations, and what you really *need* to remember is the complexity and mechanism of each sort algorithm, to choose the best fit for your dataset, when you need it.

And otherwise, when you really need to dig again in the pseudocodes, there are books (like the Art of Computer Programming by Donald Knuth), and wikipedia, and many other resources online.

> Will interviewers ever ask you to produce the codes on the spot?

Yes they will. It happened to me at least five times. But most of the time, they'll understand that you might not remember the full pseudocode on the spot, but they expect you to *know* the mechanism and complexity, and be able to reinvent the algorithm on the spot.

Though, when you do interviews, you're usually compared to other people passing the same interview, and between two candidates that passes, they'll choose the one that did the best on the tests… And then you might loose a job opportunity because someone else remembered better those algorithms.

Comment: To clarify, by producing the codes on the spot, I mean the exact code in Java/C++ etc.

PseudoCodes can be reasoned out but hard-coding will be a bit tricky. Am I required to memorize the exact syntax?

Comment: If you know the pseudo code, and you know _well_ the language you use for the interview, then figuring out the code in a given language is easy!

Comment: And interviewers won't mind if you forgot the exact name of function X, or the method Y l, or if you invent a function that's trivial and not important for your exercise. They want to know whether you really know how to code, and if you know the 101 of algorithmics

Comment: Thanks. I am just preparing myself for the future and trying to take in as much as I could. So as of right now, just try and memorize the pseudocode for the different sorting?

Comment: Well, my advice to you is to *UNDERSTAND* the different algorithms, and then implement them in different languages (at least one low level procedural like C, and one high level functional like Haskell, Scala or OCaml). As computer science is the science of Logic, understanding is the key, then exercising will make it stick.

Comment: My advice to you for such algorithms would be to be methodical, and make a checklist: what's the end condition? How do you iterate/recurse (from N, how you get to N+1)? what's the start condition (what data do you need to launch the algorithm)? then, what's the O() complexity of the algo?

Comment: Also, check the book "cracking the code interviews", it's based on feedback from Apple, Google, Amazon, Yahoo and Facebook recruutment processes. Worth a read.